# largest geodesic ball inside a small portion of Euclidean submanifold

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Suppose that $M\subseteq\mathbb R^D$ is a compact smooth Riemannian submanifold of dimension $d$, having normal injectivity radius $\tau$. Let $x_0\in M$ be a point, and $\delta\in (0,\tau)$ sufficiently small. I would like to know if $M\cap B_{\mathbb R^D}(x_0,\delta)$ has $d$-dimensional Hausdorff measure at least $(1/2)\delta^d\omega_d$ where $\omega_d$ is the volume of unit ball in $\mathbb R^d$.

My approach: since $\delta\in (0,\tau)$, there is a diffeomorphism $\exp_{x_0}:B_{T_{x_0}M}(0,\delta)\cong B_M(x_0,\delta)$. Now, by Taylor expansion of the volume form (theorem 9.9/9.10 of Gray's *Tubes*) we know, for example, that volume of $B_M(x_0,\delta)$ is more than $0.9$ times the volume of $B_{\mathbb R^d}(0,\delta)$; hence, if I know that $B_M(x_0,\delta)\subseteq M\cap B_{\mathbb R^D}(x_0,\delta)$, for example, then I will be done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For all $x,y \in M$, $d(x,y) \geq \lvert x - y \rvert$, where $d$ is the distance function on the manifold. Therefore for every point $x_0 \in M$ and every radius $\rho > 0$,
\begin{equation}
B_M(x_0,\rho) = \{ x \in M \mid d(x,x_0) < \rho \}
\subset \{ x \in M \mid \lvert x - x_0 \rvert < \rho \}.
\end{equation}
This holds in particular for small radii, for example when $\rho = \delta$ in your description.

Comment: thank you so much.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on the "largest" part? Can we say like $B_M(x_0,C\rho)\subseteq B_{\ell^2}(x_0,\rho)$ for some large $C>1$? Since my application requires using an asymptotic expansion, I need to know how a large geodesic ball can be squeezed in.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking. What notation is this on the right-hand side? Note that improvements that are generally valid will be hard to come by, because you could have equality in $d(x,y) \geq \lvert x - y \rvert$, for example if $M$ contains a flat portion of a plane around $x_0$.

Comment: $B_{\ell^2}(x_0,\rho)=\{x:||x-x_0||_2<\rho\}$.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation with "flat portion"; this reminds me that I need to keep in mind the curvature conditions I have for my particular problem.